# How to create a text file in unix server by running the java code in unix server?

Tags: java, unix

Can any one tell me how to create a text file in unix server through a java code?

I tried running the below code but it doesnt work.

```
BufferedWriter output = null;
File file = new File("D:\abc.txt);
```

Please help me out!!!

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error at compile time or runtime? If yes, then what is the error? Please show your complete code, because those two lines are not a complete example.

Answer (score 4):

Well:

```
// This certainly won't create a file. It's just declaring a variable
// and giving it an initial value of null
BufferedWriter output = null;

// This has multiple problems - see below
File file = new File("D:\abc.txt);
```

That's invalid Java, to start with - you'd need "D:\abc.txt", with a closing double-quote and a double-backslash (as backslashes need escaping Java string literals). Even then:

- It will just create a `File` object, which is basically a *representation* of a file system entry. It won't create an actual file within the file system
- Unix file systems don't look like that. You'll want to write to `/home/foo/whatever` or something similar. Given that you definitely *don't* want to write to "the D drive" (as that concept is meaningless in Unix) where *do* you want to write to?

When you know where you want to write, you can use something like:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter
    (new FileOutputStream("/home/foo/abc.txt"), "utf-8"));
try {
    writer.write("This is a line of text");
} finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you don't post all of your code, I suppose the rest of the code does write to the `BufferedWriter`. You have 2 mistakes (one might just be a copy/paste issue:
1. missing closing quote (as noted by Jon Skeet)
2. you need to backslash the separator on Windows (you would use `java.io.File.separator` to be safer)

```
BufferedWriter output = null;
File file = new File("D:\\abc.txt");
```

Finally, on a Unix server you wouldn't find "D:\" name...

```
BufferedWriter output = null;
// Example if you mounted windows drive D: to /mnt/d
File file = new File("/mnt/d/abc.txt");
```